# Is there any way to loop through all properties in child component, binded in a parent component to a child in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

Is there any way to loop through all properties in *child-component*, binded in a *parent-component* to a child in angular.

Example:

**in parent-component**:

```
<app-child [a]="someval1" [b]="someval2" [c]="someval3" [d]="someval1"></app-child>
```

**in child-component**:

```
@Input() // any function or callback which will loop through show all the child property binded in parent component
```

like:

- a: someval1
- b: someval2 etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the reputation to add this as a comment - so sharing it as an answer

instead of trying to iterate over all the property bindings of a component, why not have a single property binding in the below format

```
someProp: {
 a: 'someValue',
 b: 'someOtherValue'
}
```

now, in parent you can use it like

```
<app-child [someProp]="obj" ></app-child>
```

Once you have it in this way, in child component you can easily use Object.keys(someProp)

Comment: thanks for response buddy. actually my requirement is in parent <app-child [a]="a1" [b]="b1" [c]="c1"></app-child>  .........  and in child component i can loop through and get all properties binded in parent to the child. and then in child's html i can again pass all that properties and bind to some other component like in child component <app-somecomponent  // here i can bind all properties which was binded in parent ></app-somecomponent> .